# How do I pass an array using the $.get method of jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, get

I am using following code in a script to call a servlet:

```
function dynamicallyDisplayText() {
    var doctype = document.getElementById("doctype");
    var lang = document.getElementById("lang");
    var inputNames = [];
    $("input").each(function () {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");

            if (((name) && name !== ""))) {
            inputNames.push(this);
        }
    });

$.get('ServletClass', {
    doctype: doctype,
    lang: lang,
    "inputNames": "inputNames"
}, function (responseJson) {
    $.each(responseJson, function (index, fieldvalue) {
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(fieldvalue);
    });
});
}
```

However, it's not redirecting on the servlet as intended. I want to use only the `$.get` method, so how do I pass an array to `$.get` method so that I can redirect on the servlet.

Comment: Remove the quotes around both the `inputNames`. Why would you add quotes when the other values don't have quotes ?

Comment: i have tried that way as well but that was not running.

Comment: [`$(form).serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is your friend, by the way.

Comment: but i want to use only $.get. In my case it is more convenient for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inputNames is an array of ***DOM elements***, not names, inside the `each()` function you're doing

```
inputNames.push(this);
```

where `this` is the native DOM node, not the name

change it to

```
var inputNames = [];
$("input").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");

    if (name) {
        inputNames.push( name ); // not "this"
    }
});
```

and in the $.get function

```
$.get('ServletClass', {
    doctype     : doctype,
    lang       : lang,
    inputNames : inputNames
}, function(responseJson) {
    console.log(responseJson);
});
```

---

as a sidenote, you could just replace the each function with a map instead

```
var inputNames = $.map( $("input"), function (item) { return item.name });
```

Comment: have changed all code as per your code but not redirecting on servlet.

Comment: Log the response of the ajax call, and see what you get. Added it to the code above as well.

Comment: Thanks. After logging i have found my mistakes. Now working fine. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

In `$.get` there should be

```
"inputNames": inputNames
```